# Cakephp create new image folder in webroot

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Just very plain and straight. I created new folder named "images" apart from "img" provided. But when I try to access image in that folder using absolute url like :

```
http://domain.com/images/abc.png
```

It redirect to images controller and show up now found error instead of just accessing webroot. Any idea how to let cakephp accessing webroot for that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code where you're accessing the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file is really in path `/app/webroot/images/abc.png`

then check your `.htaccess` files, if they contain this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

which will not rewrite your request if file exists (`!-f`) or if target is directory (`!-d`)

Comment: Yup, the file `abc.png` has to exist, otherwise Apache can't serve the file and the request gets handed to CakePHP (which would render a 404 - not a missing controller error
 - if debug was off).

Comment: Hi, Yes i ensure that the file exist. Btw, i have added your 2 lines in .htaccess in both cakephp root folder and /webroot/.htaccess . But somehow it still redirect to images controller which doesnt exist instead of webroot/images/abc.png when i type http://domain.com/images/abc.png.  Any more idea?

Comment: same file is in / (root), /app, /app/webroot. But tell me, what version of CakePHP do you use?